# Implicit super constructor Teleporter() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

Hello im getting the error "Implicit super constructor Teleporter() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor" any help?

If I remove the imported Teleporter class then another error appears but this one goes away. The error message is at
**public REDTeleporter(WorldServer worldIn)**

```
public REDTeleporter(WorldServer worldIn)
{
    this.worldServerInstance = worldIn;
    this.random = new Random(worldIn.getSeed());
}

public void placeInPortal(Entity entityIn, float rotationYaw)
{
    if (this.worldServerInstance.provider.getDimensionId() != 1)
    {
        if (!this.placeInExistingPortal(entityIn, rotationYaw))
        {
            this.makePortal(entityIn);
            this.placeInExistingPortal(entityIn, rotationYaw);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        int i = MathHelper.floor_double(entityIn.posX);
        int j = MathHelper.floor_double(entityIn.posY) - 1;
        int k = MathHelper.floor_double(entityIn.posZ);
        byte b0 = 1;
        byte b1 = 0;

        for (int l = -2; l <= 2; ++l)
        {
            for (int i1 = -2; i1 <= 2; ++i1)
            {
                for (int j1 = -1; j1 < 3; ++j1)
                {
                    int k1 = i + i1 * b0 + l * b1;
                    int l1 = j + j1;
                    int i2 = k + i1 * b1 - l * b0;
                    boolean flag = j1 < 0;
                    this.worldServerInstance.setBlockState(new BlockPos(k1, l1, i2), flag ? Blocks.obsidian.getDefaultState() : Blocks.air.getDefaultState());
                }
            }
        }

        entityIn.setLocationAndAngles((double)i, (double)j, (double)k, entityIn.rotationYaw, 0.0F);
        entityIn.motionX = entityIn.motionY = entityIn.motionZ = 0.0D;
    }
}

public boolean placeInExistingPortal(Entity entityIn, float p_180620_2_)
{
    boolean flag = true;
    double d0 = -1.0D;
    int i = MathHelper.floor_double(entityIn.posX);
    int j = MathHelper.floor_double(entityIn.posZ);
    boolean flag1 = true;
    Object object = BlockPos.ORIGIN;
    long k = ChunkCoordIntPair.chunkXZ2Int(i, j);

    if (this.destinationCoordinateCache.containsItem(k))
    {
        REDTeleporter.PortalPosition portalposition = (REDTeleporter.PortalPosition)this.destinationCoordinateCache.getValueByKey(k);
        d0 = 0.0D;
        object = portalposition;
        portalposition.lastUpdateTime = this.worldServerInstance.getTotalWorldTime();
        flag1 = false;
    }
    else
    {
        BlockPos blockpos4 = new BlockPos(entityIn);

        for (int l = -128; l <= 128; ++l)
        {
            BlockPos blockpos1;

            for (int i1 = -128; i1 <= 128; ++i1)
            {
                for (BlockPos blockpos = blockpos4.add(l, this.worldServerInstance.getActualHeight() - 1 - blockpos4.getY(), i1); blockpos.getY() >= 0; blockpos = blockpos1)
                {
                    blockpos1 = blockpos.down();

                    if (this.worldServerInstance.getBlockState(blockpos).getBlock() == Blocks.portal)
                    {
                        while (this.worldServerInstance.getBlockState(blockpos1 = blockpos.down()).getBlock() == Blocks.portal)
                        {
                            blockpos = blockpos1;
                        }

                        double d1 = blockpos.distanceSq(blockpos4);

                        if (d0 < 0.0D || d1 < d0)
                        {
                            d0 = d1;
                            object = blockpos;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (d0 >= 0.0D)
    {
        if (flag1)
        {
            this.destinationCoordinateCache.add(k, new REDTeleporter.PortalPosition((BlockPos)object, this.worldServerInstance.getTotalWorldTime()));
            this.destinationCoordinateKeys.add(Long.valueOf(k));
        }

        double d4 = (double)((BlockPos)object).getX() + 0.5D;
        double d5 = (double)((BlockPos)object).getY() + 0.5D;
        double d6 = (double)((BlockPos)object).getZ() + 0.5D;
        EnumFacing enumfacing = null;

        if (this.worldServerInstance.getBlockState(((BlockPos)object).west()).getBlock() == Blocks.portal)
        {
            enumfacing = EnumFacing.NORTH;
        }

        if (this.worldServerInstance.getBlockState(((BlockPos)object).east()).getBlock() == Blocks.portal)
        {
            enumfacing = EnumFacing.SOUTH;
        }

        if (this.worldServerInstance.getBlockState(((BlockPos)object).north()).getBlock() == Blocks.portal)
        {
            enumfacing = EnumFacing.EAST;
        }

        if (this.worldServerInstance.getBlockState(((BlockPos)object).south()).getBlock() == Blocks.portal)
        {
            enumfacing = EnumFacing.WEST;
        }

        EnumFacing enumfacing1 = EnumFacing.getHorizontal(entityIn.getTeleportDirection());

        if (enumfacing != null)
        {
            EnumFacing enumfacing2 = enumfacing.rotateYCCW();
            BlockPos blockpos2 = ((BlockPos)object).offset(enumfacing);
            boolean flag2 = this.func_180265_a(blockpos2);
            boolean flag3 = this.func_180265_a(blockpos2.offset(enumfacing2));

            if (flag3 && flag2)
            {
                object = ((BlockPos)object).offset(enumfacing2);
                enumfacing = enumfacing.getOpposite();
                enumfacing2 = enumfacing2.getOpposite();
                BlockPos blockpos3 = ((BlockPos)object).offset(enumfacing);
                flag2 = this.func_180265_a(blockpos3);
                flag3 = this.func_180265_a(blockpos3.offset(enumfacing2));
            }

            float f6 = 0.5F;
            float f1 = 0.5F;

            if (!flag3 && flag2)
            {
                f6 = 1.0F;
            }
            else if (flag3 && !flag2)
            {
                f6 = 0.0F;
            }
            else if (flag3)
            {
                f1 = 0.0F;
            }

            d4 = (double)((BlockPos)object).getX() + 0.5D;
            d5 = (double)((BlockPos)object).getY() + 0.5D;
            d6 = (double)((BlockPos)object).getZ() + 0.5D;
            d4 += (double)((float)enumfacing2.getFrontOffsetX() * f6 + (float)enumfacing.getFrontOffsetX() * f1);
            d6 += (double)((float)enumfacing2.getFrontOffsetZ() * f6 + (float)enumfacing.getFrontOffsetZ() * f1);
            float f2 = 0.0F;
            float f3 = 0.0F;
            float f4 = 0.0F;
            float f5 = 0.0F;

            if (enumfacing == enumfacing1)
            {
                f2 = 1.0F;
                f3 = 1.0F;
            }
            else if (enumfacing == enumfacing1.getOpposite())
            {
                f2 = -1.0F;
                f3 = -1.0F;
            }
            else if (enumfacing == enumfacing1.rotateY())
            {
                f4 = 1.0F;
                f5 = -1.0F;
            }
            else
            {
                f4 = -1.0F;
                f5 = 1.0F;
            }

            double d2 = entityIn.motionX;
            double d3 = entityIn.motionZ;
            entityIn.motionX = d2 * (double)f2 + d3 * (double)f5;
            entityIn.motionZ = d2 * (double)f4 + d3 * (double)f3;
            entityIn.rotationYaw = p_180620_2_ - (float)(enumfacing1.getHorizontalIndex() * 90) + (float)(enumfacing.getHorizontalIndex() * 90);
        }
        else
        {
            entityIn.motionX = entityIn.motionY = entityIn.motionZ = 0.0D;
        }

        entityIn.setLocationAndAngles(d4, d5, d6, entityIn.rotationYaw, entityIn.rotationPitch);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

private boolean func_180265_a(BlockPos p_180265_1_)
{
    return !this.worldServerInstance.isAirBlock(p_180265_1_) || !this.worldServerInstance.isAirBlock(p_180265_1_.up());
}

public boolean makePortal(Entity p_85188_1_)
{
    byte b0 = 16;
    double d0 = -1.0D;
    int i = MathHelper.floor_double(p_85188_1_.posX);
    int j = MathHelper.floor_double(p_85188_1_.posY);
    int k = MathHelper.floor_double(p_85188_1_.posZ);
    int l = i;
    int i1 = j;
    int j1 = k;
    int k1 = 0;
    int l1 = this.random.nextInt(4);
    int i2;
    double d1;
    int k2;
    double d2;
    int i3;
    int j3;
    int k3;
    int l3;
    int i4;
    int j4;
    int k4;
    int l4;
    int i5;
    double d3;
    double d4;

    for (i2 = i - b0; i2 <= i + b0; ++i2)
    {
        d1 = (double)i2 + 0.5D - p_85188_1_.posX;

        for (k2 = k - b0; k2 <= k + b0; ++k2)
        {
            d2 = (double)k2 + 0.5D - p_85188_1_.posZ;
            label271:

            for (i3 = this.worldServerInstance.getActualHeight() - 1; i3 >= 0; --i3)
            {
                if (this.worldServerInstance.isAirBlock(new BlockPos(i2, i3, k2)))
                {
                    while (i3 > 0 && this.worldServerInstance.isAirBlock(new BlockPos(i2, i3 - 1, k2)))
                    {
                        --i3;
                    }

                    for (j3 = l1; j3 < l1 + 4; ++j3)
                    {
                        k3 = j3 % 2;
                        l3 = 1 - k3;

                        if (j3 % 4 >= 2)
                        {
                            k3 = -k3;
                            l3 = -l3;
                        }

                        for (i4 = 0; i4 < 3; ++i4)
                        {
                            for (j4 = 0; j4 < 4; ++j4)
                            {
                                for (k4 = -1; k4 < 4; ++k4)
                                {
                                    l4 = i2 + (j4 - 1) * k3 + i4 * l3;
                                    i5 = i3 + k4;
                                    int j5 = k2 + (j4 - 1) * l3 - i4 * k3;

                                    if (k4 < 0 && !this.worldServerInstance.getBlockState(new BlockPos(l4, i5, j5)).getBlock().getMaterial().isSolid() || k4 >= 0 && !this.worldServerInstance.isAirBlock(new BlockPos(l4, i5, j5)))
                                    {
                                        continue label271;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        d3 = (double)i3 + 0.5D - p_85188_1_.posY;
                        d4 = d1 * d1 + d3 * d3 + d2 * d2;

                        if (d0 < 0.0D || d4 < d0)
                        {
                            d0 = d4;
                            l = i2;
                            i1 = i3;
                            j1 = k2;
                            k1 = j3 % 4;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (d0 < 0.0D)
    {
        for (i2 = i - b0; i2 <= i + b0; ++i2)
        {
            d1 = (double)i2 + 0.5D - p_85188_1_.posX;

            for (k2 = k - b0; k2 <= k + b0; ++k2)
            {
                d2 = (double)k2 + 0.5D - p_85188_1_.posZ;
                label219:

                for (i3 = this.worldServerInstance.getActualHeight() - 1; i3 >= 0; --i3)
                {
                    if (this.worldServerInstance.isAirBlock(new BlockPos(i2, i3, k2)))
                    {
                        while (i3 > 0 && this.worldServerInstance.isAirBlock(new BlockPos(i2, i3 - 1, k2)))
                        {
                            --i3;
                        }

                        for (j3 = l1; j3 < l1 + 2; ++j3)
                        {
                            k3 = j3 % 2;
                            l3 = 1 - k3;

                            for (i4 = 0; i4 < 4; ++i4)
                            {
                                for (j4 = -1; j4 < 4; ++j4)
                                {
                                    k4 = i2 + (i4 - 1) * k3;
                                    l4 = i3 + j4;
                                    i5 = k2 + (i4 - 1) * l3;

                                    if (j4 < 0 && !this.worldServerInstance.getBlockState(new BlockPos(k4, l4, i5)).getBlock().getMaterial().isSolid() || j4 >= 0 && !this.worldServerInstance.isAirBlock(new BlockPos(k4, l4, i5)))
                                    {
                                        continue label219;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            d3 = (double)i3 + 0.5D - p_85188_1_.posY;
                            d4 = d1 * d1 + d3 * d3 + d2 * d2;

                            if (d0 < 0.0D || d4 < d0)
                            {
                                d0 = d4;
                                l = i2;
                                i1 = i3;
                                j1 = k2;
                                k1 = j3 % 2;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    int k5 = l;
    int j2 = i1;
    k2 = j1;
    int l5 = k1 % 2;
    int l2 = 1 - l5;

    if (k1 % 4 >= 2)
    {
        l5 = -l5;
        l2 = -l2;
    }

    if (d0 < 0.0D)
    {
        i1 = MathHelper.clamp_int(i1, 70, this.worldServerInstance.getActualHeight() - 10);
        j2 = i1;

        for (i3 = -1; i3 <= 1; ++i3)
        {
            for (j3 = 1; j3 < 3; ++j3)
            {
                for (k3 = -1; k3 < 3; ++k3)
                {
                    l3 = k5 + (j3 - 1) * l5 + i3 * l2;
                    i4 = j2 + k3;
                    j4 = k2 + (j3 - 1) * l2 - i3 * l5;
                    boolean flag = k3 < 0;
                    this.worldServerInstance.setBlockState(new BlockPos(l3, i4, j4), flag ? Blocks.obsidian.getDefaultState() : Blocks.air.getDefaultState());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    IBlockState iblockstate = Blocks.portal.getDefaultState().withProperty(BlockPortal.AXIS, l5 != 0 ? EnumFacing.Axis.X : EnumFacing.Axis.Z);

    for (j3 = 0; j3 < 4; ++j3)
    {
        for (k3 = 0; k3 < 4; ++k3)
        {
            for (l3 = -1; l3 < 4; ++l3)
            {
                i4 = k5 + (k3 - 1) * l5;
                j4 = j2 + l3;
                k4 = k2 + (k3 - 1) * l2;
                boolean flag1 = k3 == 0 || k3 == 3 || l3 == -1 || l3 == 3;
                this.worldServerInstance.setBlockState(new BlockPos(i4, j4, k4), flag1 ? Blocks.obsidian.getDefaultState() : iblockstate, 2);
            }
        }

        for (k3 = 0; k3 < 4; ++k3)
        {
            for (l3 = -1; l3 < 4; ++l3)
            {
                i4 = k5 + (k3 - 1) * l5;
                j4 = j2 + l3;
                k4 = k2 + (k3 - 1) * l2;
                this.worldServerInstance.notifyNeighborsOfStateChange(new BlockPos(i4, j4, k4), this.worldServerInstance.getBlockState(new BlockPos(i4, j4, k4)).getBlock());
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

public void removeStalePortalLocations(long p_85189_1_)
{
    if (p_85189_1_ % 100L == 0L)
    {
        Iterator iterator = this.destinationCoordinateKeys.iterator();
        long j = p_85189_1_ - 600L;

        while (iterator.hasNext())
        {
            Long olong = (Long)iterator.next();
            REDTeleporter.PortalPosition portalposition = (REDTeleporter.PortalPosition)this.destinationCoordinateCache.getValueByKey(olong.longValue());

            if (portalposition == null || portalposition.lastUpdateTime < j)
            {
                iterator.remove();
                this.destinationCoordinateCache.remove(olong.longValue());
            }
        }
    }
}

public class PortalPosition extends BlockPos
{
    public long lastUpdateTime;
    private static final String __OBFID = "CL_00000154";

    public PortalPosition(BlockPos pos, long p_i45747_3_)
    {
        super(pos.getX(), pos.getY(), pos.getZ());
        this.lastUpdateTime = p_i45747_3_;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class `Teleporter` doesn't have a reachable empty constructor. You could add one. If you make it `protected` only a sub-class can call it. Or, you can call whatever non-empty constructor `Teleporter` does have. Assuming `Teleporter` has a constructor that takes a `WorldServer` then you need something like

```
public REDTeleporter(WorldServer worldIn)
{
    super(worldIn);
    this.worldServerInstance = worldIn;
    this.random = new Random(worldIn.getSeed());
}
```

Comment: Wow that was easy :p sorry for wasting your time im new with this.